# For loop recursively through folder in windows cmd for file rename

Tags: image, command-line, recursion, rename, windows-scripting

I'm trying to iterate through folders with images to create thumbnails using ImageMagic, and rename thumbnail files with `small_` prefix.

when I execute this in single folder, it works great:

```
FOR %a in (*.jpg) DO convert %a -thumbnail 30% small_%a
```

To loop through subfolders, I just need /R flag:

```
FOR /R %a in (*.jpg) DO convert %a -thumbnail 30% small_%a
```

This will result into new name for thumbnail 
`small_c:\images\image.jpg` which is wrong :)

How can I get `small_` prefix into file name while recursing through subfolders in script, i.e. from `c:\images\image.jpg` to `c:\images\small_image.jpg` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think this is may suit your case.

```
for /R %i in (*.jpg) DO convert %i -thumbnail 30% %~di%~pi%~ni_small%~xi
```

Comment: I'll just use small_ in front of file name: for /R %i in (*.jpg) DO convert %i -thumbnail 30% %~di%~pismall_%~ni%~xi

Comment: this would not work for me no matter what, until i found in the manual http://ss64.com/nt/for.html that the correct syntax is double-%, e.g.: for /R %%i in (*.jpg) DO convert %%i...

Comment: The double-`%` is only necessary if running the command in a batch file.  If running the `for` loop at the command prompt, only a single `%` is required.